# TypeScript: Simplify type with default generic parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Suppose I have the following object:

```
const questions = {
    whoCreatesIssues: {
        options: {
            sameTeam: {
                id: 'SAME_TEAM'
            },
            management: {
                id: 'MANAGEMENT'
            }
        }
    },
    issuesUseCase: {
        options: {
            engineering: {
                id: 'ENGINEERING'
            },
            product: {
                id: 'PRODUCT'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a type `SurveyQuestionOptionsKeys` such that, for example,

```
SurveyQuestionOptionsKeys<'issuesUseCase'> == 'engineering' | 'product'
```

Currently, I'm using the following two types to achieve this:

```
type _SurveyQuestionsOptionsKeys<T extends typeof questions, K extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K]> = keyof T[K][K2]
type SurveyQuestionsOptionsKeys<K extends keyof typeof questions> = _SurveyQuestionsOptionsKeys<typeof questions, K, 'options'>
```

How can I simplify this to only one type instead of relying on two? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be pretty simple if you allow yourself to extract `Questions` into a type of its own first:

```
type Questions = typeof questions;
type SurveyQuestionsOptionsKeys<K extends keyof Questions> = keyof Questions[K]['options'];
type X = SurveyQuestionsOptionsKeys<'issuesUseCase'>;
```

(you could also replace the two occurrences of `Questions` with `typeof questions` and it'll work, but that's a bit repetitive and will make the logic slightly harder to understand at a glance)